# php gettext with html

Tags: php, internationalization

I am trying to translate documentation which is stored in a database in html from English to Portuguese:

```
    msgid ""
"<strong>Page Name:</strong> Manual Audit<br /><strong>Location:</strong> Audit Management -&gt; Manual Audit<br /><strong>URL:</strong> <a href=\"manual_audit\">http://qagator.com/manual_audit</a><br /><br /><strong>Description:</strong><br /><em>This page is used by Quality Assurance to audit employee responses in chats, calls, tickets, and IS chats.</em><br /><br /><strong>Functions:</strong><br /><br /><strong>Who are we auditing</strong>: <em>This input takes a full name of the employee we want to audit. This then loads a form where each audited item can be entered and saved.</em><br /><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"><img src=\"images/docs/manual_audit_start.png\" alt=\"\" /></div><br /><strong>Resume Audit</strong>:&nbsp;<em>This will list any audits that the agent has previously started but has not yet submitted.</em><br /><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"><img src=\"images/docs/manual_audit_resume.png\" alt=\"\" /></div><br /><strong>Audit Form</strong>: <em><em>Form that takes the Item ID, Item Type, Summary and Quick Notes. The form saves after each item submission.&nbsp;<br /></em></em><ul><li>Finished Items slideout:&nbsp;<em>This slideout shows the current items reviewed and is shown throughout the entire audit. &nbsp;It catalogues your progress so far on an audit, allowing for full review of the work reviewed up to that point of the audit.</em></li></ul><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"><img src=\"http://qagator.com/upload/manual_audit_view.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"1045\" height=\"475\" /></div><br /><ul><li>Save Item: <em>This button saves the item you've completed and refreshes the form for the next item.</em></li></ul><ul><li>Finish Audit: <em>Upon resume or after one item has been saved, this button becomes available and is used to proceed to the Audit summarization page.</em></li></ul><br />Finished Page: <em>This page has text areas for a list of positives, concerns and a summary, as well as input for the reason for the audit</em><br /><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"><img src=\"images/docs/manual_audit_final.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>"
msgstr ""
"<strong> Página Nome : </ strong > Auditoria manual <br /> <strong> Localização: </ strong> Gestão Fiscal -> Auditoria manual <br /> <strong> URL: </ strong > <a href=\"manual_audit\"> http://qagator.com/manual_audit </ a > <br /> <br /> <strong> Descrição : </ strong> <br /> <em> Esta página é utilizada pela Garantia da Qualidade para auditar respostas dos funcionários em chats , telefonemas , bilhetes , e IS chats </ em> <br /> <br /> <strong> Funções . : </ strong > <br /> <br /> <strong> quem estamos auditando </ strong> : <em> Esta entrada tem um nome completo do funcionário que deseja auditar . Isso, então, carrega um formulário onde cada item auditado podem ser inseridos e salvos. </ Em> <br /><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"> <200b><200b><img src=\"images/docs/manual_audit_start.png\" alt=\"\" /> < / div><br /> <strong> Resume Auditoria </ strong> : . <em> Isto irá listar quaisquer auditorias que o agente já havia iniciado, mas ainda não apresentou </ em> <br /><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"> <200b><200b><img src=\"images/docs/manual_audit_resume.png\" alt=\"\" /> < / div><br /> <strong> Formulário de Auditoria </ strong> : <em> <em> formulário que leva o ID do Item , Tipo de artigo , resumo e notas rápidas . A forma salva após cada submissão item. <br /> < / Em> </ em><ul><li> itens acabados deslizante : <em> Este deslizante mostra os itens atuais revisada e é mostrado ao longo de toda a auditoria. Ele cataloga o seu progresso até agora em uma auditoria , permitindo a revisão completa da obra resenhada até aquele momento da auditoria. </ em> </ li></ ul><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"> <200b><200b><img src = \ " http://qagator.com/upload/manual_audit_view.png \ " alt = \ "\ " width = \ " 1045 \ " height = \ " 475 \" / > </ div><br /><ul><li> Salvar item : . <em> Este botão salva o item que você terminou e refresca o formulário para o próximo item </ em> </ li></ ul><ul><li> Finish Auditoria: . <em> Ao currículo ou após um item foi salvo , este botão fica disponível e é usado para avançar para a página de resumo de Auditoria </ em> </ li></ ul><br /> Terminado Página: <em> Esta página tem áreas de texto para uma lista de pontos positivos , preocupações e um resumo , bem como entrada para a razão para a auditoria </ em> <br /><div style=\"padding-left: 30px;\"> <200b><200b><img src=\"images/docs/manual_audit_final.png\" alt=\"\" /> < / div>"
```

When translating I get the following error:

```
[qagator_production@QAGator public_html]$ msgfmt -o locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po:1465:1665: invalid control sequence
locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po:1465: keyword "http" unknown
locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po:1465:1672: syntax error
locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po:1465:1727: invalid control sequence
locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po:1465:1742: invalid control sequence
locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po:1465:1764: invalid control sequence
msgfmt: found 6 fatal errors
```

Any assistance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to review your markup - it would make life a lot easier to help you if your code was formatted

Comment: Understood. I took out the formatting while trying to get it to work with msgid (I thought maybe the newlines were causing issues). Also, tinymce is saving the html so cant help formatting since non-developers are creating the documentation.

Comment: Any additional advice?

Comment: You need to minimize your data to see what is wrong. If it is html tag, resource file format, or else. For example, try "<h1>test</h1>" instead of that long message first. If that does not work, then try "test" without html tags. When the errors cease, you would know what caused the errors.